Woocommerce Bookings - only 1 booking per day
I am trying to limit the availability of the resources so that they can be booked only once per day.
Ex: Opening times: 9am to 1pm. If a resource is booked Monday, from 10am to 1pm, it should not be possible to book the resource from 9am to 10am.
This is what I have done so far, which is working for products with only 1 resource available:
$fullObj = array();
        
foreach ( $existing_bookings as $existing_booking ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $existing_booking, 'WC_Booking' ) ) {
        continue;
    }
    // echo '<pre>';
    // print_r($existing_booking);
    // echo'</pre>';
    $InnerObj = array();
    $dateObj = array();
    $res = array();
    $InnerObj['person_counts']  = $existing_booking->get_person_counts()[0];
    $InnerObj['order_id'] = $existing_booking->get_order_id();
    $InnerObj['resource_id'] = $existing_booking->get_resource_id();
    $InnerObj['resource_order_id'] = $existing_booking->ID;
    $InnerObj['date_created'] = date('Y-m-d', $existing_booking->get_date_created());
    $InnerObj['date_modified'] = date( 'Y-m-d', $existing_booking->get_start() );
    $InnerObj['end'] = date( 'Y-m-d', $existing_booking->get_end() );
    $res[$existing_booking->get_resource_id()] = 1; 
    $dateObj[date( 'Y-m-d', $existing_booking->get_start() )] = $res; 
    //array_push($booked_day_blocks['fully_booked_days'], $dateObj);
    $date_format = date( 'Y-n-j', $existing_booking->get_start() );
    $booked_day_blocks[ 'fully_booked_days' ][ $date_format ][ $existing_booking->get_resource_id() ] = 1;
}

However, if the product has more than 1 resource available, it doesn't take it into consideration, and the day is marked as fully booked, when it should only be so when the last resource available has been booked.
